# Bitmap Compress giving empty file (0 bytes)

Tags: android, bitmap

EDIT - Another Udpate!

Interestingly I tried the same code on my nexus 5, the image preview is correct but the image itself is just black.

The devices being used are s3 minis, on these the image cannot be opened and no preview is displayed.

I am aiming at sdk version 16.

Further to this, I plugged my nexus back into my dev machine and opened as a storage device, image is not shown.

I then emailed the image from my phone to myself and the bloody thing  displays fine, which has confused me either even further, the only thing I can think of is that the image is too big to display?

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I am trying to create an image and then save it to file, it displays fine on screen and the file is created, however the file cannot be opened and has a size of 0 bytes. Has anyone had this problem before? This is my code:

```
private class SampleView extends View {


        public SampleView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setFocusable(true);

        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            EANMaker e = new EANMaker("123456789963");
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            View view = this;
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            view.setDrawingCacheQuality(view.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);

            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);


            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
            c.drawRect(0, 0, 500, 500, paint);
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
            paint.setTextSize(40);
            paint.setTextScaleX(1.f);
            paint.setAlpha(0);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            c.drawText("Carton ID", 60, 40, paint);
            paint.setTextSize(160);
            Typeface tf = gettypeFace(MyActivity.this, "ean.ttf");
            paint.setTypeface(tf);
            c.drawText(e.getCode(), 60, 180, paint);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawBitmap(b, 50,50, paint);

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/barcode.png");
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                fos = null;
            } catch (IOException ee) {
                ee.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception p)
            {
                p.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                if (fos != null) {
                    try {
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException ee) {
                        ee.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public Typeface gettypeFace(Context c, String assetPath) {
        synchronized (cache) {
            if (!cache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
                try {
                    Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
                            assetPath);
                    cache.put(assetPath, t);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "Could not get typeface '" + assetPath
                            + "' because " + e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return cache.get(assetPath);
        }
    }
```

EDIT, I have been playing around with this and can now get a 6k file, however this still cannot be opened, I suspect that one of the canvases is not being drawn into the bitmap but I am at a complete loss on what else to do, my latest code is as follows

```
    private class SampleView extends View {


    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


        EANMaker e = new EANMaker("123456789963");
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(900, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        canvas.drawBitmap(b,0,0, paint);

        //paint.setTextScaleX(1.f);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(40);
        c.drawText("Carton LABEL", 20, 40, paint);
        c.drawText("Carton ID = 1      Packed By = Test User", 20, 80, paint);
        c.drawText("Despatch Date = 05/08/2014", 20, 120, paint);
        paint.setTextSize(160);
        Typeface tf = gettypeFace(MyActivity.this, "ean.ttf");
        paint.setTypeface(tf);
        c.drawText(e.getCode(), 60, 280, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);


        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/barcode.png");
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            fos = null;
        } catch (IOException ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception p)
        {
            p.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException ee) {
                    ee.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}

public Typeface gettypeFace(Context c, String assetPath) {
    synchronized (cache) {
        if (!cache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
            try {
                Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
                        assetPath);
                cache.put(assetPath, t);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Could not get typeface '" + assetPath
                        + "' because " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
        return cache.get(assetPath);
    }
}
```

and my logcat to prove there is no errors:

```
08-05 13:13:02.371  26627-26627/com.example.imagetest I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1443)
08-05 13:13:03.082  26627-26627/com.example.imagetest D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
08-05 13:13:03.082  26627-26627/com.example.imagetest D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
08-05 13:13:03.092  26627-26627/com.example.imagetest D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
08-05 13:13:03.112  26627-26627/com.example.imagetest D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
08-05 13:13:03.162  26627-26627/com.example.imagetest I/System.out﹕ Full code: 1234567899633
08-05 13:13:03.162  26627-26627/com.example.imagetest I/System.out﹕ Generated code: $!23E5GH-ijjgdd!
08-05 13:13:03.192  26627-26627/com.example.imagetest D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 84K, 13% free 9464K/10823K, paused 22ms, total 32ms
08-05 13:13:03.192  26627-26627/com.example.imagetest I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 12.093MB for 1728016-byte allocation
08-05 13:13:03.222  26627-26629/com.example.imagetest D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 39K, 12% free 11112K/12551K, paused 13ms+3ms, total 31ms
08-05 13:13:03.222  26627-26627/com.example.imagetest D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 9ms
```

Comment: You are logging out any potential exceptions. So is there anything in the log cat?

Comment: @weston not a thing, like I say, the file actually creates, but it cannot be opened either on the device or in Ubuntu

Comment: `compress` returns a `boolean`. Is this `==true`?

Comment: @weston, yup, returns true

Comment: The `flush` should not be necessary... but also shouldn't hurt.

Comment: @weston - removed it just in case, no change though, its very frustrating!

Comment: I just noticed you are doing this `onDraw`. That means it's hammering that file re-writing it all the time even while you are copying it or trying to open it.

Comment: Wouldn't it just draw once when setContentView(new SampleView(this)); is called? I am stopping the app before trying to access the file

Comment: Just to test this, I moved the code to the oncreate and created Canvas canvas = new Canvas(), still same result

Comment: Yeah you're right, it's not going to keep doing it. I can't see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are being created, they are just to big to be opened correctly on the device.

Comment: This helped me, copy images from device to somewhere else and u will see the result